# Crystal Reports and strongly typed datasets yields empty report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, strongly-typed-dataset

I am converting an ASP.Net app from VS 2003 to VS 2005 as a starting point.  The app uses Crystal Reports and binds using ADO.Net to a strongly typed dataset (XSD).  I had to change some of Crystal Code to work with the newer version of Crystal.  Now, when I run the page, the report generates, but none of the fields fill in.  I have seen lots of people having the same problem with no real solutions out there.  I decided to create a fresh project that does the same thing to remove the conversation from VS 2003 to 2005 as a possible cause of the problem.  So my sample program has a button that runs a query, fills the dataset and assigns it to the report.  The report displays the headers only.  The code is below.  I have no idea what to try next.

```
    DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();

    SqlConnection conn = 
       new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from mytable", conn);
    da.Fill(ds);

    ReportDocument rep = new ReportDocument();
    rep.Load(Server.MapPath("crystalreport.rpt"));
    rep.SetDataSource(ds);

    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rep;
    CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

I also created the DataSet1.XSD based on the same MYTABLE table.  I get no errors or any indication anything is wrong except that the fields in the report don't populate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would take some debugging to know for sure why it's not working for you. Have you looked at the resulting dataset in a debugging session, and seen if it fills correctly?

Here's a good example of a method to work from.

```
SqlConnection cnn;
string connectionString = null;
string sql = null;

connectionString = "data source=SERVERNAME;initial catalog=DATABASENAME;user id=USERNAME;password=PASSWORD;";
cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
cnn.Open();
sql = "select * from mytable";
SqlDataAdapter dscmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
dscmd.Fill(ds, "mytable");
cnn.Close();

CrystalReport1 objRpt = new CrystalReport1();
objRpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[1]);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Comment: At first glance your code is pretty much the same as mine, except for one tiny detail...you specify the explicit table in the SetDataSource where I sent the report the whole DataSet.  Once I changed it to the table reference, everything filled in nicely.  Thanks.

Comment: I figured that was probably the key to why it wasn't working. I'm a big copy/paste guy, so I like having full examples to build from because I always forget about little details such as this. Glad it helped.